# Is there guarantee of privacy to buy onion hosting?

Tags: anonymity, security, onion-routing, website, web-hosting

I see many people owning a onion site uses his own server (maybe just place the server in his home?)

But traditionally for a regular non-onion site we usually buy hosting. Can I buy hosting for a onion site? Would it leak my privacy or anonymity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But traditionally for a regular non-onion site we usually buy hosting.
>   Can I buy hosting for a onion site?

Absolutely! You can pay for a VPS or a managed server or even co-locate your own server.

Here are some things to keep in mind:

If you use a VPS, what will keep you provider from viewing what's in your storage?

If you use a managed server or you co-locate your own server, will the provider have access to the machine without your permission?

If your provider is sniffing packets, they can see that you are connected to the Tor network but they **cannot** see who visits you or what you are doing unless they break into your VM or server. I genuinely believe that most don't care what you do as long as you don't break the terms of your agreement (like setting up an exit node) or it is determined that you are doing something highly illegal.

> Would it leak my privacy or anonymity?

That's on you. If you run a website that is insecure, uses lots of javascript or any other functionality that can be hacked or can give away your true IP, then you can harm your own anonymity. A good rule of thumb is to choose a website platform that has the least functionality required to do what you want but is also regularly patched.

I personally run a wordpress blog onion site on my hosted mail server. I keep it patched. I don't use any extra plugins, and I don't give it out publicly. Does my provider know that I run it? I seriously doubt it. Would they care? Probably not unless the laws change in the country where it is hosted saying that onion services are illegal.

Finally, your question is, "is there guarantee of privacy to buy onion hosting?".  **No. There is never any guarantee at all.** They best you can do is understand how Tor and web security works and work from there. Sorry I can't give an easy positive answer because there isn't one.

Comment: Good answer. I really appreciate it. Maybe I shouldn’t ask, why do you run blog on an onion site? Is it because you don’t want others see it? One thing I doubt is why some website owners will choose running on onion site, since it’s hard to advertise, hard to be seen by others, hard to get known. Well, if you don’t want to answer me this  no problem :)

Comment: I run onion services because I believe in anonymity. I run a public tech blog on wordpress.com that I have linked to my day job. My onion service is for things that I don't want associated with my work. I can share it with like minded people but I don't want the internet to know everything about me.